# Query to group based on the sorted table result

Tags: sql, grouping, sequence

Below is my table

```
a  1
a  2
a  1
b  1
a  2
a  2
b  3
b  2
a  1
```

My Expected output is

```
a  4
b  1
a  4
b  5
a  1
```

I want them to be grouped if they are in sequence.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column to specify the ordering, your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms supports window functions, you can use the row_number difference to assign the same group to consecutive values (which are the same) in one column. After assigning the groups, it is easy to sum the values for each group.

```
select col1,sum(col2)
from (select t.*, 
      row_number() over(order by someid) 
      - row_number() over(partition by col1 order by someid) as grp
      from tablename t
     ) x
group by col1,grp
```

Replace tablename, col1,col2,someid with the appropriate column names. someid should be the column to be ordered by.